# How to display duplicated attribute value using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am a newbie in xslt and i want to ask for a help in creating an .xsl file that will validate if the attribute value has the same value.

```
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101">aa</book>
    <book id="bk102">bb</book>
    <book id="bk103">cc</book>
    <book id="bk101">dd</book>
</catalog>
```

choose when the value of the '@id' is not same as the other '@id'value then it will display:

`aa
bb
cc
dd`
other wise it will display:

your '@id' has same value of 'bk101'

Comment: Please select **either** XSLT 1.0 **or** XSLT 2.0 - not both. Also post the expected output **as code**, not as a description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="book-by-id" match="book" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="book"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(key('book-by-id', @id)) > 1">
                <xsl:text>*** DUPLICATE ID ***</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">*** DUPLICATE ID ***</book>
   <book id="bk102">bb</book>
   <book id="bk103">cc</book>
   <book id="bk101">*** DUPLICATE ID ***</book>
</catalog>
```